# The payload is invalid when i add some dummy data at my URL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I encrypt my url

```
  <a href="{{url('loan-close/'.Crypt::encryptString($loan_list->id))}}">Close Loan</a>
```

First time the result show=OK.But when I input `some dummy` data with my old data  then I face this error.

**Error**

```
 Illuminate \ Contracts \ Encryption \ DecryptException
```

The payload is invalid

**Route**

```
`Route::get('loan-close/{id}','Admin\LoanController@loan_close');`
```

**Controller**

```
   public function loan_close($id){
    echo Crypt::decryptString($id);exit;
  }
```

how can handel this type of error.

[how can i check that `encryptString = false` ]

Comment: Why use Crypt::encryptString instead of encrypt() right away.

Comment: Please explain what _“when I input some dummy data with my old data”_ actually means.

Comment: Wellcome to STACKOVERFLOW! Brother id you can describe the problem briefly .. will get a good solution or question may be deleted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation you can use try catch block and catch the decryptexception like this.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;

try {
    $decrypted = decrypt($encryptedValue);
} catch (DecryptException $e) {
    //
}
```